# Yellow underline by @Autowired

Tags: javascript, spring

IntelliJ is showing a yellow underline by @Autowired, but it works properly. How can I git rid of the yellow underline? And what does mean the yellow underline?

Here is a picture to illustrate it:
[image]

Comment: What message do you see when you hover your cursor on the underlined @Autowired? The only thing that I see is indentation, but can be something else. Usually there's a dialog with good information why the underline is there.

Comment: I see this message "Field injection is not recomended"

Comment: Press alt + enter on the field, IDEA should help you to make a constructor/setter based injection

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this before and it helped me, but the teacher recommended us to don't use it.

Comment: When I press alt + enter on the field, IDEA should help you to make a constructor/setter, I see that the@Autowired is disappeared form the code.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE is telling you that it is a bad practice to inject on properties of a class.

For the example that you show, the [constructor injector](https://springframework.guru/best-practices-for-dependency-injection-with-spring/) is recommended.

Comment: Thanks, but could you please explain how I can write with @Autowired?